# Where are smbd system links in UBUNTU 12.04?

Tags: samba, ubuntu-12.04, upstart, runlevel

After installing Samba on UBUNTU 12.04, I checked the system link run level directories and were not able to find smbd links. This is interesting because smbd is started automatically on reboot.

Here is the ls of my rc directories:

```
secadmin@SAM:~$ ls /etc/rc*
/etc/rc.local

/etc/rc0.d:
K20firewall    K20libnss-ldap  K20testscript  K20watchdog     K21postgresql  README       S30urandom       S35networking  S60umountroot
K20freeradius  K20sam          K20updater     K20watchdogdev  K80slapd       S20sendsigs  S31umountnfs.sh  S40umountfs    S90halt

/etc/rc1.d:
K20firewall    K20libnss-ldap  K20testscript  K20watchdog     K21postgresql  K80slapd  S30killprocs  S70pppd-dns
K20freeradius  K20sam          K20updater     K20watchdogdev  K77ntp         README    S70dns-clean  S90single

/etc/rc2.d:
README         S19slapd     S20freeradius   S20sam         S20updater   S20watchdogdev  S50rsync      S70pppd-dns  S99grub-common  S99rc.local
S19postgresql  S20firewall  S20libnss-ldap  S20testscript  S20watchdog  S23ntp          S70dns-clean  S75sudo      S99ondemand

/etc/rc3.d:
README         S19slapd     S20freeradius   S20sam         S20updater   S20watchdogdev  S50rsync      S70pppd-dns  S99grub-common  S99rc.local
S19postgresql  S20firewall  S20libnss-ldap  S20testscript  S20watchdog  S23ntp          S70dns-clean  S75sudo      S99ondemand

/etc/rc4.d:
README         S19slapd     S20freeradius   S20sam         S20updater   S20watchdogdev  S50rsync      S70pppd-dns  S99grub-common  S99rc.local
S19postgresql  S20firewall  S20libnss-ldap  S20testscript  S20watchdog  S23ntp          S70dns-clean  S75sudo      S99ondemand

/etc/rc5.d:
README         S19slapd     S20freeradius   S20sam         S20updater   S20watchdogdev  S50rsync      S70pppd-dns  S99grub-common  S99rc.local
S19postgresql  S20firewall  S20libnss-ldap  S20testscript  S20watchdog  S23ntp          S70dns-clean  S75sudo      S99ondemand

/etc/rc6.d:
K20firewall    K20libnss-ldap  K20testscript  K20watchdog     K21postgresql  README       S30urandom       S35networking  S60umountroot
K20freeradius  K20sam          K20updater     K20watchdogdev  K80slapd       S20sendsigs  S31umountnfs.sh  S40umountfs    S90reboot

/etc/rcS.d:
README  S37apparmor  S55urandom
```

After doing some research on Internet, I found that normally the links must be in the rc directories. Can anyone tell me where they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now an upstart job. Look in /etc/init/smbd.conf for all info on it.